# How to create a DAX measure that computes cumulative sum and is also responsive to the evaluation context in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's think of a project management scenario where projects status change from Open (1) to In-Progress (2) and finally Closed (3). In this example I have 10 projects. My requirement is to produce a count of projects based on a date and/or status type. The key thing here is that the value returned by the measure is related to the evalutation context.

Here's the Project Status table:

[image]

Now have a look at the table visual below which is the expected result, at least in part.

[image]

For example: on 6th Feb we had 4 projects in the system where 2 were open, 1 was In-Progress and 1 was closed. That gives me a total of 4 projects as of 6th Feb. It looks at the data of 7 rows which is self and the previous 6 rows. If I want to know the status of the projects as of today we just need to look at the last entry on 24th Dec which will give me 10.

When I display this measure which calculates the number of projects on a table visual without dates and status types columns, I would expect the value of 10. In this scenario my context filter doesn't have dates and status types to filter by.

If my visualization (matrix) only has **Status Type** as the column field I would expect:

[image]

If my matrix has Date as a row field and Status Type as column field then I would expect to see what I've shown earlier.

What I'm earnestly asking is for your advice on the best way to tackle this challenge. As a first attempt I've come up with something which is not giving me no where near what I expect but rather than trying to fix what I've got I would appreciate your comments if I'm tackling this thing the right way.

```
Project Status Count = 

VAR MaxKnownDate =
    MAX ( 'Project Status'[Status Date] )

VAR StatusSummaryBase =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Date'
        ,'Date'[Date]
    )
    
 VAR StatusSummary =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            StatusSummaryBase,
              "Latest Count", 
              VAR DateSnapshot = 'Date'[Date]
              RETURN
                CALCULATE (
                    COUNTX (
                         'Project Status',
                          'Project Status'[Project Id]
                          ),
                    LASTNONBLANK (
                        FILTER(
                            ALL('Date'),
                            'Date'[Date] <= DateSnapshot
                        ),
                        COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE('Project Status'))
                    )
                )
            
        )
        ,FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Project Status'[Status Date] ),
            'Project Status'[Status Date] <= MaxKnownDate
        )
    )       

VAR Result =
    SUMX(StatusSummary, [Latest Count])
    
RETURN
    Result
```

I understand I may still need to check for the presence of context filters such as data and status type in order to produce the right calculation.

Comment: On 15th March, I can see project id 2,3 and 5 are open. How you are getting 2 in the Open (1) column on that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these below steps to achieve your required output-

**Step-1:** Create a **Calculated Column** with this below code-

```
date_part = 
DATE(
    YEAR(your_table_name[status date]),
    MONTH(your_table_name[status date]),
    DAY(your_table_name[status date])
)
```

**Step-2:** Now create this below 4 **Measures**-

```
Open (1) = 

var current_row_pid = MIN('your_table_name'[project id])
var current_row_date_part = MIN('your_table_name'[date_part])

var _table1 = 
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[date_part] <= current_row_date_part
    ),
    'your_table_name'[project id],
    "project status id", MAX('your_table_name'[project status id])
)

var _table2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    _table1,
    "status type id", 
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        'your_table_name'[status type id],
        'your_table_name'[project id],[project id],
        'your_table_name'[project status id],[project status id]
    )
)

RETURN 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        _table2,
        [status type id] = 1
    )
) + 0
```

```
in-progress (2) = 

var current_row_pid = MIN('your_table_name'[project id])
var current_row_date_part = MIN('your_table_name'[date_part])

var _table1 = 
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[date_part] <= current_row_date_part
    ),
    'your_table_name'[project id],
    "project status id", MAX('your_table_name'[project status id])
)

var _table2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    _table1,
    "status type id", 
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        'your_table_name'[status type id],
        'your_table_name'[project id],[project id],
        'your_table_name'[project status id],[project status id]
    )
)

RETURN 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        _table2,
        [status type id] = 2
    )
) + 0
```

```
closed (3) = 

var current_row_pid = MIN('your_table_name'[project id])
var current_row_date_part = MIN('your_table_name'[date_part])

var _table1 = 
SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[date_part] <= current_row_date_part
    ),
    'your_table_name'[project id],
    "project status id", MAX('your_table_name'[project status id])
)

var _table2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    _table1,
    "status type id", 
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        'your_table_name'[status type id],
        'your_table_name'[project id],[project id],
        'your_table_name'[project status id],[project status id]
    )
)

RETURN 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        _table2,
        [status type id] = 3
    )
) + 0
```

```
total_project = [Open (1)] + [in-progress (2)] + [closed (3)]
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: Man, your calculations are absolutely spot on. Well done!
I'm sorry my calculations on the post were a bit off.

Comment: Hi @user1309226, please get my updated answer with all necessary Column and Measure codes.